# RavenDB session management for a desktop application

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, ravendb

I'm trying to use a embedded RavenDB database for a small desktop application written in C# and WPF (using MVVM). Right now I'm asking myself how to handle the sessions the right way. I'm loading some items at the start of the application which may get updated at some time.

What's the best way to handle that?
The solutions I've tought of or read so far are:

- use a single session for the whole lifespan of the application - I haven't read about that one, so I don't think it should be a preferred solution
- open a session after an object has been changed, load the object again from the server, use a library like ValueInjector to overwrite all values from the local object and save those changes - seems more like a hack fix
- Save the etag for each object and use it with the store method to replace the complete object on the database - doesn't seem like a good solution either

So neither of these possibilities seem very good and unfortunately 90% of all samples seem to be for MVC controllers only.
Is there any way to reattach an object from an old, closed session? Or is there any other recommended way to achieve what I want?